# SQl Query Send, Open, Click, , Unique Click

Tags: sql, dataview, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am working on requirement where i need to have the query to populate Sends, Click, Open, Unique Clicks and Unsubscribe.
Data I'm getting in all the fields are okay. But Clicks and Unique Clicks data are coming as same number. I believe the Unique Clicks count is okay, but the Clicks count for each email should be more. Which i'm not getting with my query.

Can someone please help here ?

Here is my query -

```
SELECT
   jou.JourneyName AS 'SFMC Journey Email Name',
   COUNT(s.JobID) AS 'Sent',
   COUNT(o.JobID) AS 'Unique Opens',
   COUNT(Distinct c.[subscriberkey]) AS 'Clicks',
   COUNT(c.JobID) AS 'Unique Clicks',
   COUNT(u.JobID) AS 'Unsubscribes',
   (COUNT(s.JobID)- COUNT(b.JobID)) as 'Delivered'

FROM _Sent s  LEFT JOIN _Job j ON j.JobID = s.JobID
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON s.JobID = o.JobID and s.ListID = o.ListID and s.BatchID = o.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID and o.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Click c ON s.JobID = c.JobID and s.ListID = c.ListID and s.BatchID = c.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID and c.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Bounce b ON s.JobID = b.JobID and s.ListID = b.ListID and s.BatchID = b.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID and b.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Unsubscribe u ON s.JobID = u.JobID and s.ListID = u.ListID and s.BatchID = u.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = u.SubscriberID and u.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _JourneyActivity ja ON j.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
LEFT JOIN _Journey jou ON ja.VersionID = jou.VersionID
WHERE jou.JourneyName IS NOT NULL AND jou.JourneyStatus in ('Running', 'Stopped')
AND jou.JourneyName like 'PROD%' or jou.JourneyName like 'UAT%'
GROUP BY jou.JourneyName,j.EmailName, jou.LastPublishedDate, j.DeliveredTime
HAVING COUNT('SFMC Journey Email Name') >1
```

Comment: You need IsUnique to get unique clicks